# My session ID's stopped working

Tags: php, session, sessionid, session-storage

I have been working on writing a program and the session ID's have been working for several days. Now all of a sudden they are not working anymore. Any advice? The script codes are below for the test script I wrote to test passing the session ID's.

This is how I have the login page started, with no line breaks before this code.

```
<?php session_start();
?>
<!--HTML HEADER-->
<form action="sessionID.php" method="post">
name: <input name="stName" type="text" /><br/>
pass: <input name="newPass" type="text" /><br/>
<input name="" type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

It is passed through another page to test passing through a HREF link. Here is the top of that script.

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['student']=$_POST['stName'];
```

Final page to echo the session ID.

```
<?php session_start();
$student = $_SESSION['student'];
echo session_id();
```

Anything I am doing wrong...?

Comment: What do you mean "not working?" Are they empty? What do you get when you var_dump() a session? Does $_POST['stName'] have a value? Does session_id() have a value? Why are you echoing session_id() and not $_SESSION['student']? WHYYYYY? ;)

Comment: Try `echo $_SESSION['student'];` instead if you're expecting an echoed output. It worked for me, and echoed my name when entered in the field, then passed on to the 3rd page I setup.

Comment: echoing `session_id();` will echo a series of number/letters, and not the actual name, if that's what you're looking to get.

Comment: Now by "not working anymore", what is the expected result?

Comment: @Tim Seems like we've lost the connection, *"as it were"*. Take care, see you on a later question, it's all yours ;-) I am off to Lah-Lah Land.

Comment: echo session_id(); comes up with a really long string of numbers and letters.

Comment: the expected result is the name used at login.

Comment: Just print_r($_SESSION); it is any array, I think you know how to get value form an array

Comment: ok, so if I echo $SESSIO['student']; i get the desired result.

Comment: In the program the exact same code is not working.. I am assigning $username = $SESSION['student'] and using $username to echo the username.

Comment: @Tim - sorry, new to this site, didn't realize people responded so quickly.

Comment: The problem is still occurring... I don't know if I broke it by using `session_destroy();`, (I have since removed the destroy command). I changed `$SESSION['student']` to `$SESSION['user']` after removing the destroy command, and it returned the `$student` value once, and no longer returns the `$student` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I redirected after verifying username password, I used `http://www.domainname`.
I switched the redirect to `http://domainname` (no www.) and `$_SESSION['user']` works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You saved your value to $_SESSION['student']

Use:

```
<?php session_start();

$student = $_SESSION['student'];

//echo session_id(); 

echo $student;
```

?>

Comment: I have this in the program... <?php session_start();
$_SESSION['student'] = $_POST['stName'];
$username=$_SESSION['student'];

Comment: Could the fact that I used `session_destroy()` to log out be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Echoing `session_id();` will echo a series of number/letters, and not the actual name.

In order to echo the (student) name of the input given from a form is:

```
echo $_SESSION['student'];
```