# Unwanted independent sessions for two separate pages

Tags: php, apache, xampp, sessionid

I am stumped. Everybody says if you use session_start that you should get a single session even when you open multiple browser windows. However, it seems that my sessions are page specific.

When I load page one (index.php), it gives as a Session ID: sr51j9hhrjjrvbrfboek15l4e4 with an empty $_SESSION array

I then log in on a webpage (login.php) that generates a new Session ID: v2t8844nglg7uvnsrbr6k9ms43 with a $_SESSION array with various variables.

When I then reload page one, it will display the old session ID, not the new one as expected. It is page linked because if I copy load page two in tab one, it will give the same session ID as the page in tab 2, and visa versa.

I have added the rule

> CacheDisable /local_files

to the httpd.conf file with no effect.

I uses Apache 2.4 (XAMPP installation for windows), with the http://php-login.net advanced login script.

Top of page (before the HTML tag):

> session_start();
>
> require_once('includes/connection.php');

followed by:

> echo var_dump($_SESSION);
>
> echo session_save_path();
>
> echo 'Session ID: '.session_id();

at the top of the page in the body tag.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running chrome, by any chance?  In any case, try using different tabs, not different windows.

Comment: No, Firefox last version.

Comment: Have you tried multiple tabs instead of multiple windows?

Comment: yes. Multiple tabs gives the same issue. It is page linked because if I copy load page two in tab one, it will give the same session ID as the page in tab 2, and visa versa. Hence I suspect it is a caching issue with the XAMPP/Apache installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found the answer here: [My session ID's stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669613/my-session-ids-stopped-working?rq=1)

One page was localhost:8001, while the second was 127.0.0.1:8001, which are treated by the server as two separate pages for the purpose of sessions, while serving the same page.

Answer (score 2):

session_start() will create a single session that can be used across the same browser/tabs.

Comment: It does not in my case. It is not that simple... :-(

Comment: You should be able to try the following example code:

<?php
session_start();

print 'This is my session: '. session_id();

Comment: That was what I used to identify the problem, the two pages give different session IDs back.